# Treat filetype FILE as a TXT in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

I want to know how I can associate filetype `FILE` in Windows 10 to be treated as a TXT filetype.

The annoyance of using Windows is you have these filetypes called FILE is that no program can be associated with it to open it. So I wonder if there's a registry tweak or something that can be done so that you can just simply read them in a text editor such as Notepad++, sure I can add the `*.file` extension into Notepad++ but that doesn't allow you actually open them in Notepad++ because when you click on it, Windows still prompts you what you'd like to do with the following file I'm trying to open.

[image: Filetype FILE]
[image: how to]

Just makes me wish that Windows was a little more similar to Linux how it can tell what the MIME-type is and then open it up in a text editor without asking what you'd like to do with it. -- And before you ask, yes, I do have "Show file extension names" enabled in the Folder Options. And no it's not just as simple as suffixing a file extension name after it to change it, because that's not what I'm trying to do here.

Comment: There isn't a file extension. That's the problem. With no extension Windows doesn't know what type of file it is. So, it asks you what to do with it.

Comment: out of interest what kind of contents is typically in files with a `.file` extension, what program creates such files? From  a windows perspective it's the most ridiculous extension i've ever heard of. And from a linux perspective I suppose one might want to identify files that aren't directories, by sticking .file on every file but i've never heard of anybody doing that.

Comment: You're using Notepad++ which adds a context menu entry by default. It's the same number of clicks just with a bigger delay to open a file. Though it's not what you want it might be worth to point out in case you missed it. @barlop it doesn't have a `.file` extension, it doesn't have any extension. As such you can't associate a default program (easily) on Windows.

Comment: @barlop - These kind of unknown filetypes that display themselves as FILE are usually typically text files with data in them. Windows doesn't understand what kind of file they are specifically because it expects a file extension name to identify them properly. ie; *.txt, *.doc, etc... this is typically because Windows doesn't use MIME-types like UNIX machines do.

Comment: -1 You wrote in your question "I can add the *.file"    Consider that if a file has no extension then it may be listed as File that doesn't mean it is *.file!  If you go to CMD and do dir *.file  it won't list extensionless files.  If you go in linux and do ls *.file it won't list extensionless files. So why are you calling them `.file` ?

Comment: @barlop -1 First of all, don't be rude. Second this is how Windows handles them and classifies these filetypes as, and I only said if you read properly that I COULD add it to Notepad++ as a custom extension to try open them, but it doesn't work like that.

Comment: @user94959 even there I don't think it's classifying them as `.file` it's classifying them as `File`  To put a dot there suggests that what follows is an extension and in your case it's not.

Answer (score 1):

*@user94959*, try to navigate to the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Unknown\shell` key. There should be a default `REG_SZ` value of `runas` referencing the corresponding `runas` key below which in turn should contain a default `REG_EXPAND_SZ` value pointing to the default program. **Note** that the last default value **must be** of `REG_EXPAND_SZ` type - not just `REG_SZ`.